# Similarity between vectors

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to calculate the likelihood that the two measurements are exactly equivalent. The measurements are taken on the same day by two different individuals separated by **10 minutes**. The day starts at **4am (act1)** and ends at **3.50am (act144).** At each time-step, different measurements were taken by 2 individuals. People are identified by **serial and pnum** numbers. If the measurements taken on the same day (**DiaryDateAct**) are identical, I would like to replace it with 10; otherwise, I'd like to replace it with 0.

At the end of the same day, I would like to determine that the total sum of the measurements is identical.

Such as the desired output:

`serial(11011202)_DiaryDateAct(14/12/2014)_110 = act1_1 - act1_15 = 150`.
`serial(11011202)_DiaryDateAct(14/12/2014)_7330 = act1_79 - act1_86 = 80`....an so on

How can I do this for **n** number of id's (serial(11011202)_DiaryDateAct(14/12/2014)) and **i** number of measurements (eg. 110, 7330)

For example:

Data structure

[image]

Data sample:

```
  structure(list(serial = structure(c(11011202, 11011202, 11011202, 
11011202), label = "Household number", format.stata = "%12.0g"), 
    pnum = structure(c(1, 4, 4, 1), label = "Person number", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    daynum = structure(c(1, 1, 2, 2), label = "Diary number", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    DiaryDate_Act = structure(c(16415, 16415, 16418, 16418), label = "Diary Day - ACTUAL DATE", class = "Date", format.stata = "%tdD_m_Y"), 
    act1_1 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 04:00-04:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_2 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 04:10-04:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_3 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 04:20-04:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_4 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 04:30-04:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_5 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 04:40-04:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_6 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 04:50-05:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_7 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 05:00-05:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_8 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 05:10-05:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_9 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 05:20-05:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_10 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 05:30-05:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_11 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 05:40-05:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_12 = structure(c(8219, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 05:50-06:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_13 = structure(c(310, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 06:00-06:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_14 = structure(c(3210, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 06:10-06:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_15 = structure(c(3110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 06:20-06:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_16 = structure(c(7241, 110, 110, 111), label = "Primary activity: 06:30-06:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_17 = structure(c(210, 110, 110, 310), label = "Primary activity: 06:40-06:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_18 = structure(c(3819, 110, 110, 3110), label = "Primary activity: 06:50-07:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_19 = structure(c(210, 110, 110, 3310), label = "Primary activity: 07:00-07:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_20 = structure(c(210, 310, 110, 3310), label = "Primary activity: 07:10-07:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_21 = structure(c(210, 210, 110, 210), label = "Primary activity: 07:20-07:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_22 = structure(c(3310, 310, 110, 210), label = "Primary activity: 07:30-07:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_23 = structure(c(3210, 310, 110, 210), label = "Primary activity: 07:40-07:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_24 = structure(c(3210, 9210, 110, 210), label = "Primary activity: 07:50-08:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_25 = structure(c(3210, 9210, 110, 3310), label = "Primary activity: 08:00-08:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_26 = structure(c(3210, 9210, 110, 3310), label = "Primary activity: 08:10-08:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_27 = structure(c(3110, 9210, 110, 7241), label = "Primary activity: 08:20-08:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_28 = structure(c(3110, 9210, 110, 7241), label = "Primary activity: 08:30-08:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_29 = structure(c(3110, 9210, 110, 7241), label = "Primary activity: 08:40-08:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_30 = structure(c(3110, 9210, 110, 7241), label = "Primary activity: 08:50-09:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_31 = structure(c(7259, 2110, 111, 3430), label = "Primary activity: 09:00-09:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_32 = structure(c(5140, 2110, 111, 3430), label = "Primary activity: 09:10-09:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_33 = structure(c(5140, 2110, 111, 3210), label = "Primary activity: 09:20-09:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_34 = structure(c(5140, 2110, 3110, 3210), label = "Primary activity: 09:30-09:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_35 = structure(c(5140, 2110, 7330, 3210), label = "Primary activity: 09:40-09:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_36 = structure(c(5140, 2110, 7330, 3210), label = "Primary activity: 09:50-10:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_37 = structure(c(7259, 2110, 7330, 210), label = "Primary activity: 10:00-10:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_38 = structure(c(7259, 2110, 7330, 5110), label = "Primary activity: 10:10-10:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_39 = structure(c(7259, 2110, 7330, 3210), label = "Primary activity: 10:20-10:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_40 = structure(c(7259, 2110, 7330, 3210), label = "Primary activity: 10:30-10:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_41 = structure(c(7259, 2110, 7330, 5110), label = "Primary activity: 10:40-10:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_42 = structure(c(7259, 2110, 7330, 5110), label = "Primary activity: 10:50-11:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_43 = structure(c(3110, 2110, 8212, 5110), label = "Primary activity: 11:00-11:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_44 = structure(c(5140, 2110, 8212, 5120), label = "Primary activity: 11:10-11:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_45 = structure(c(5140, 2110, 8212, 5120), label = "Primary activity: 11:20-11:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_46 = structure(c(8120, 2110, 8212, 5120), label = "Primary activity: 11:30-11:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_47 = structure(c(8120, 2110, 8212, 5120), label = "Primary activity: 11:40-11:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_48 = structure(c(8120, 2110, 8212, 9360), label = "Primary activity: 11:50-12:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_49 = structure(c(8120, 2110, 8212, 3610), label = "Primary activity: 12:00-12:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_50 = structure(c(8120, 2110, 8212, 3611), label = "Primary activity: 12:10-12:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_51 = structure(c(8120, 2110, 8212, 3611), label = "Primary activity: 12:20-12:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_52 = structure(c(8120, 2110, 8212, 3611), label = "Primary activity: 12:30-12:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_53 = structure(c(8120, 2110, 8212, 3611), label = "Primary activity: 12:40-12:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_54 = structure(c(8120, 2110, 8212, 3611), label = "Primary activity: 12:50-13:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_55 = structure(c(210, 2110, 3610, 3611), label = "Primary activity: 13:00-13:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_56 = structure(c(210, 2110, 3610, 210), label = "Primary activity: 13:10-13:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_57 = structure(c(210, 210, 3610, 210), label = "Primary activity: 13:20-13:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_58 = structure(c(210, 210, 3610, 210), label = "Primary activity: 13:30-13:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_59 = structure(c(210, 210, 3610, 210), label = "Primary activity: 13:40-13:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_60 = structure(c(210, 210, 3610, 210), label = "Primary activity: 13:50-14:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_61 = structure(c(9360, 210, 3610, 3610), label = "Primary activity: 14:00-14:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_62 = structure(c(9360, 210, 3610, 3610), label = "Primary activity: 14:10-14:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_63 = structure(c(9360, 210, 3610, 9360), label = "Primary activity: 14:20-14:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_64 = structure(c(9360, 2110, 3610, 9360), label = "Primary activity: 14:30-14:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_65 = structure(c(9360, 2110, 3610, 3240), label = "Primary activity: 14:40-14:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_66 = structure(c(9360, 2110, 3610, 3240), label = "Primary activity: 14:50-15:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_67 = structure(c(3610, 2110, 3610, 3240), label = "Primary activity: 15:00-15:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_68 = structure(c(3610, 2110, 3610, 3110), label = "Primary activity: 15:10-15:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_69 = structure(c(3610, 2110, 3610, 3110), label = "Primary activity: 15:20-15:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_70 = structure(c(3610, 9210, 3610, 3110), label = "Primary activity: 15:30-15:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_71 = structure(c(3610, 9210, 3610, 3110), label = "Primary activity: 15:40-15:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_72 = structure(c(3610, 9210, 3610, 3110), label = "Primary activity: 15:50-16:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_73 = structure(c(3240, 9210, 3610, 3110), label = "Primary activity: 16:00-16:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_74 = structure(c(3240, 9210, 3610, 3110), label = "Primary activity: 16:10-16:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_75 = structure(c(3110, 9210, 3610, 3110), label = "Primary activity: 16:20-16:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_76 = structure(c(3110, 9210, 3240, 3110), label = "Primary activity: 16:30-16:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_77 = structure(c(3110, 9210, 3240, 3110), label = "Primary activity: 16:40-16:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_78 = structure(c(3110, 9210, 3240, 3110), label = "Primary activity: 16:50-17:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_79 = structure(c(7220, 7330, 7330, 3110), label = "Primary activity: 17:00-17:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_80 = structure(c(7220, 7330, 7330, 5310), label = "Primary activity: 17:10-17:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_81 = structure(c(7220, 7330, 7330, 5310), label = "Primary activity: 17:20-17:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_82 = structure(c(7220, 7330, 7330, 5310), label = "Primary activity: 17:30-17:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_83 = structure(c(7220, 7330, 7330, 5310), label = "Primary activity: 17:40-17:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_84 = structure(c(7220, 7330, 7330, 5310), label = "Primary activity: 17:50-18:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_85 = structure(c(210, 7330, 7330, 3110), label = "Primary activity: 18:00-18:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_86 = structure(c(210, 7330, 7330, 3110), label = "Primary activity: 18:10-18:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_87 = structure(c(210, 2120, 7330, 210), label = "Primary activity: 18:20-18:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_88 = structure(c(210, 2120, 7330, 210), label = "Primary activity: 18:30-18:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_89 = structure(c(210, 2120, 2120, 210), label = "Primary activity: 18:40-18:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_90 = structure(c(8210, 2120, 2120, 210), label = "Primary activity: 18:50-19:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_91 = structure(c(8210, 210, 310, 3240), label = "Primary activity: 19:00-19:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_92 = structure(c(8210, 210, 8212, 3240), label = "Primary activity: 19:10-19:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_93 = structure(c(8210, 210, 8212, 3240), label = "Primary activity: 19:20-19:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_94 = structure(c(8210, 8210, 8212, 3240), label = "Primary activity: 19:30-19:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_95 = structure(c(8210, 8210, 8212, 3240), label = "Primary activity: 19:40-19:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_96 = structure(c(8210, 8210, 8212, 3240), label = "Primary activity: 19:50-20:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_97 = structure(c(3130, 8210, 8212, 3130), label = "Primary activity: 20:00-20:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_98 = structure(c(3130, 8210, 8212, 3130), label = "Primary activity: 20:10-20:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_99 = structure(c(3130, 8210, 8212, 3130), label = "Primary activity: 20:20-20:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_100 = structure(c(3130, 3110, 8212, 8210), label = "Primary activity: 20:30-20:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_101 = structure(c(3130, 210, 8212, 8210), label = "Primary activity: 20:40-20:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_102 = structure(c(5110, 2120, 8212, 8210), label = "Primary activity: 20:50-21:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_103 = structure(c(7220, 2120, 8212, 8210), label = "Primary activity: 21:00-21:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_104 = structure(c(7220, 2120, 5140, 8210), label = "Primary activity: 21:10-21:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_105 = structure(c(7220, 2120, 5140, 8210), label = "Primary activity: 21:20-21:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_106 = structure(c(7220, 310, 5140, 8210), label = "Primary activity: 21:30-21:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_107 = structure(c(7220, 8210, 5140, 8210), label = "Primary activity: 21:40-21:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_108 = structure(c(7220, 8210, 5140, 8210), label = "Primary activity: 21:50-22:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_109 = structure(c(5110, 310, 110, 310), label = "Primary activity: 22:00-22:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_110 = structure(c(5110, 110, 110, 310), label = "Primary activity: 22:10-22:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_111 = structure(c(5110, 110, 110, 310), label = "Primary activity: 22:20-22:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_112 = structure(c(5110, 110, 110, 310), label = "Primary activity: 22:30-22:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_113 = structure(c(5110, 110, 110, 310), label = "Primary activity: 22:40-22:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_114 = structure(c(5110, 110, 110, 310), label = "Primary activity: 22:50-23:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_115 = structure(c(5110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 23:00-23:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_116 = structure(c(5110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 23:10-23:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_117 = structure(c(5110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 23:20-23:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_118 = structure(c(5110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 23:30-23:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_119 = structure(c(7220, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 23:40-23:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_120 = structure(c(7220, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 23:50-00:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_121 = structure(c(7220, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 00:00-00:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_122 = structure(c(7220, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 00:10-00:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_123 = structure(c(7220, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 00:20-00:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_124 = structure(c(7220, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 00:30-00:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_125 = structure(c(7220, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 00:40-00:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_126 = structure(c(7220, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 00:50-01:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_127 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 01:00-01:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_128 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 01:10-01:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_129 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 01:20-01:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_130 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 01:30-01:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_131 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 01:40-01:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_132 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 01:50-02:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_133 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 02:00-02:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_134 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 02:10-02:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_135 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 02:20-02:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_136 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 02:30-02:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_137 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 02:40-02:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_138 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 02:50-03:00", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_139 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 03:00-03:10", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_140 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 03:10-03:20", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_141 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 03:20-03:30", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_142 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 03:30-03:40", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_143 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 03:40-03:50", format.stata = "%8.0g"), 
    act1_144 = structure(c(110, 110, 110, 110), label = "Primary activity: 03:50-04:00", format.stata = "%8.0g")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `group_by` the date, `summarize` using an `ifelse` on the `diff` of the two rows to assign the 10 or 0, then `sum` the resulting columns:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(serial, DiaryDate_Act) %>%
  summarize(across(starts_with("act"), ~ifelse(diff(.x) == 0, 10, 0))) %>%
  mutate(sum = apply(.[grep("^act", names(.))], 1, sum)) %>%
  select(-starts_with("act")) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>     serial DiaryDate_Act   sum
#>      <dbl> <date>        <dbl>
#> 1 11011202 2014-12-11      370
#> 2 11011202 2014-12-14      470
```

Comment: thank you for the code and for your time., is it possible to find the sum of a specific measurement? For example  110 only or for 7330 only. Thanks

Comment: thank you for your help. The code works on the example provided but when I am using my original data I receive the following error. Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `sum = apply(.[grep("^act", names(.))], 1, sum)`.
x `sum` must be size 1, not 7988.
i The error occurred in group 1: serial = 11011202, DiaryDate_Act = 2014-12-11. I checked and tehre are no NA's. Could you help me please